How to parse soap xml request in ASP.NET Core 8 Web API
I am working on a task where there is old vb code needs to be migrated to an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API.
I need to create an API which accepts xml request with soap action header as string and then parse the string to xml and getting values in the body also name of body tag.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <soap12:Body>
           <SendX xmlns="url">
            <!--Body Content-->
            <firstname>ABC</firstname>
            <lastname>XYZ</lastname>
            <phone>07878787878</phone>
           </SendX>
         </soap12:Body>
       </soap12:Envelope>

Above is the sample request. I need to parse the string xml request and get the individual values

Web API is for REST services only - it does not support SOAP. WCF used to support SOAP, but it hasn't been ported to .NET Core by MS - there is a "spin-off" called "CoreWCF" which did this - check that out for SOAP services on .NET Core
